# What is the recommended error_reporting() setting for development? What about E_STRICT?

Tags: php, error-reporting

Typically I use `E_ALL` to see anything that PHP might say about my code to try and improve it.

I just noticed a error constant `E_STRICT`, but have never used or heard about it, is this a good setting to use for development? The manual says:

> Run-time notices. Enable to have PHP suggest changes to your code which will ensure the best interoperability and forward compatibility of your code.

So I'm wondering if I'm using the best `error_reporting` level with `E_ALL` or would that along with `E_STRICT` be the best? Or is there any other combination I've yet to learn?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In PHP 5, the things covered by `E_STRICT` are not covered by `E_ALL`, so to get the most information, you need to combine them:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

In PHP 5.4, `E_STRICT` will be included in `E_ALL`, so you can use just `E_ALL`.

You can also use

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

which will always enable *all* errors. Which is more semantically correct as:

```
error_reporting(~0);
```

Comment: Just notice that with PHP >= 5.4 the E_STRICT is included withing E_ALL

Comment: @hakre, I'm not sure I understand your edit on this answer. You're clearly implying that on 'esoteric systems', it is possible that `-1 != ~0`. What are these esoteric systems, and do they really exist? Would I be right to guess that PHP's integers are stored in whatever format the C compiler used to compile PHP uses, and that you're thinking of a hypothetical scenario in which somebody compiles PHP on, say, a one's complement C compiler? Anyway, wouldn't simply modifying Gordon's code snippet be better than leaving what's effectively an "actually, the last paragraph is wrong" edit?

Comment: -1 is a number, - a numeric operator. depending on how negative integers are handled it can represent ~0 but must not. Where it doesn't, that are those systems which I named "esoteric". What technically is wrong is that you want to use the bit-operator ~ instead of a numeric operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967360/what-does-this-operator-mean-here this is what you normally want to express. So the code is less wrong in using the more correct expression. And yes, I have experienced it once. But that's a bit ago, last time I was asked I already couldn't reproduce from mind.

Comment: @hakre, I've undone the edit. This is about hard science, not semantics. **Both are** technically correct. Until you can **name one** machine where `error_reporting(-1)` gives you different observed behavior from `error_reporting(~0)`.

Answer (score 10):

Use the following in php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Also you should install [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org), it can highlight your errors in blinding bright colors and print useful detailed information.

Never let any error or notice in your code, even if it's harmless.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the higher you set the error reporting level in development phase, the better.

In a live environment, you want a slightly (but only slightly) reduced set, but you want them logged somewhere that they can't be seen by the user (I prefer `syslog`).

http://php.net/error_reporting

`E_ALL | E_STRICT` for development with PHP before 5.2.0.

5.2 introduces `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` and 5.3 introduces `E_DEPRECATED` and `E_USER_DEPRECATED`.  You'll probably want to turn those on if you're running one of those versions.

If you wanted to use magic numbers you could just set the `error_reporting` value to some fairly high value of `2^n-1` - say, `16777215`, and that would really just turn on all the bits between `1..n`.  But I don't think using magic numbers is a good idea...

In my opinion, PHP has dropped the ball a bit by having `E_ALL` not really be all.  But apparently it's going to be fixed in PHP 6...

Answer (score 2):

In newer PHP versions, E_ALL includes more classes of errors. Since PHP 5.3, E_ALL includes everything *except* E_STRICT. In PHP 6 it will alledgedly include even that. This is a good hint: it's better to see more error messages rather than less.

What's included in E_ALL is documented in the [PHP predefined constants](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) page in the online manual.

Personally, I think it doesn't matter all that much if you use E_STRICT. It certainly won't hurt you, especially since it may prevent you from writing scripts that have a small chance of getting broken in future versions of PHP. On the other hand, in some cases strict messages may be too noisy, perhaps especially if you're in a hurry. I suggest that you turn it on by default and turn it off when it gets annoying.

Comment: E_STRICT is included in E_ALL as of 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `error_reporting = -1`
It will always consist of all bits (even if they are not in E_ALL)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your long term support plans for this code, debugging with `E_STRICT` enabled may help your code to continue working in the distant future, but it is probably overkill for day-to-day use.  There are two important things about `E_STRICT` to keep in mind:

1. [Per the manual](https://www.php.net/error_reporting), most `E_STRICT` errors are generated at compile time, not runtime.  If you are increasing the error level to `E_ALL` within your code (and not via *php.ini*), you may never see `E_STRICT` errors anyway.
2. `E_STRICT` is contained within `E_ALL` under PHP 6, but not under PHP 5.  If you upgrade your server to PHP6, and have `E_ALL` configured as described in #1 above, you will begin to see `E_STRICT` errors without requiring any additional changes on your part.

Comment: E_STRICT is included in E_ALL as of 5.4. not PHP 6

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly speaking of error_reporting, I'd **strongly** suggest using any IDE that automatically shows parsing errors and common glitches (eg, assignment in condition).

Zend Studio for Eclipse has this feature enabled by default, and since I started using it, it has been helping me **a lot** at catching errors before they occur.

For example, I had this piece of code where I was caching some data in the `$GLOBALS` variable, but I inadvertently wrote `$_GLOBALS` instead. The data never got cached up, and I'd never knew if Zend didn't tell me: "Hey, this `$_GLOBALS` thingy appears only once, that might be an error".

Answer (score -1):

ini_set("display_errors","2");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);

Comment: OK, PHP's function names are case insensitive, but you should rather use it the way it should be used (e.g. `error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT )`, where the function's name is not written with capital letters). By the way, `E_ALL` doesn't contain `E_STRICT` in PHP versions less than 5.4.