# What does this ~ operator mean here?

Tags: php

Example:

```
set_error_handler(array($this, 'handleError'), E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE);
```

what does that suppose to mean?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is the [bitwise not operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_NOT) (also called "complement"). That is the bits set in `~ $a` are those that are not set in `$a`.

So then

```
E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE
```

is the bits set in `E_ALL` and those not set in `E_STRICT`, `E_WARNING` and `E_NOTICE`. This basically says all errors except strict, warning and notice errors.

Answer (score 17):

It's the [bitwise-not operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). For example the bitwise negation of a number with binary representation `01011110` would be `10100001`; every single bit is flipped to its opposite.

Comment: Although that is the technical explanation, that explanation isn't helpful unless you realize that `E_STRICT`, `E_WARNING`, `E_NOTICE` et. al. are integers and are simultaneously being combined with the `&` bitwise operator.

Answer (score 7):

The distinction between bitwise (&, |, ~) and non-bitwise (&&, ||, !) operators is that bitwise are applied across *all* bits in the integer, while non-bitwise treat an integer as a single "true" (non-zero) or "false" (zero) value.

Say, `$flag_1 = 00000001` and `$flag_2 = 00000010`. Both would be "true" for non-bitwise operations, (`$flag_1 && $flag_2` is "true"), while the result of `$flag_1 & $flag_2` would be 00000000 and the result of `$flag_1 | $flag_2` would be 00000011. `~$flag_2` would be 11111101, which when bitwise-ANDed to a running result would *clear* that bit position (xxxxxx0x). `$flag_2` bitwise-ORed to a running result would *set* that bit position (xxxxxx1x).

Answer (score 1):

See [Bitwise Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) : it's the "not" operator *(quoting)* :

> `~ $a`
>   
> Bits that are set in `$a` are
>   not set, and vice versa.

Which means, taking an example inspired from what you posted, that this portion of code :

```
var_dump(decbin(E_STRICT));
var_dump(decbin(~E_STRICT));
```

Will get you this output :

```
string '100000000000' (length=12)
string '11111111111111111111011111111111' (length=32)
```

*(Add a couple of `0` for padding on the left of the first line, and you'll see what I mean)*

Removing the padding from the second output, you get :

```
100000000000
011111111111
```

Which means the `~` operator gave a `0` bit for each bit that was equal to `1` in the intput -- and vice-versa,

Answer (score 1):

It's the `not` **bitwise** operator. Read about bitwise operators here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php