# What does ~ do in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

In [this file](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/MinecraftQuery.class.php) i saw this "~" and wondered what id does. I'ved tried googling, but google doesn't search for characters, like if you search for ? : you have to search for question mark colon.

Comment: +1 for the dupe, but to give you a helping hand - it is the bitwise NOT operator. It flips all the bits in the operand. And FYI the symbol itself is called a [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967360/what-does-this-operator-mean-here

Comment: That there funny symbol "~" is called a tilde.

Comment: An irony +1 because you placed a link instead of just putting the fragment of the PHP code you were concerned about into the question. That was *very* helpful. Irony +1 (Yes not really, but you get a present anyway).