# PHP: Is there any benefit to writing strict code?

Tags: php, error-reporting, strict

When I set `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`, my code produces `Undefined variable` errors. I can solve them, but I am wondering whether there is any difference in speed or memory usage between writing code that passes strict checks, and just turning `E_STRICT` off?

Comment: Never never never , develop without error_reporting(E_ALL)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no mechanical benefit. You are, however, protected from doing really common, really dumb things like not always initializing a variable before using it - because with `E_STRICT` on, PHP will generate an error instead of allowing functions to break in potentially-catastrophic, and probably-invisible ways.

For example, it's completely conceivable that a database-backed application uses a variable that isn't initialized by all possible execution paths:

```
// Adds an allergy to the user's records
public function Add($AllergyID) {
    $Patient = $this->Patient->Load();

    if ($Patient->Insurance->StartDate < now()) {
          $Allergies = $Patient->Allergies->Get();
          $Allergies[] = $AllergyID;
    }

    $Patient->Allergies->Set($Allergies);
}
```

Eventually it doesn't get initialized, and somebody's medical records table is silently truncated.

In short, you should always develop with all warnings: it's your first line of defense. When it comes time to move your code into production, though, you absolutely want error reporting **off.** You don't want malicious users gaining insight into the inner workings of your application, or - *worse* - your database.

Answer (score 1):

There is NO speed Benefit, but while using PHP 5.2.0. or before you should use E_ALL | E_STRICT for the development purposes.

But for the PHP 5.2.0 above E_STRICT is included in the E_ALL itself.

Or you can use error_reporting(-1); Which will always include everything, even if they are present in E_ALL.

use the below stackoverflow question for further reference
[What is the recommended error_reporting() setting for development? What about E_STRICT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74847/what-is-the-recommended-error-reporting-setting-for-development-what-about-e)

Answer (score 0):

less errors result in better speed;
maintainability will be incresed;
memory enhancement maybe too, because of log won't be flus