# Display values in PHP that are Std Class

Tags: php

All,
I have the following code to get some posts from Tumblr:

```
$baseHostname = "name.tumblr.com";
$tumblrConsumerKey = "asfd"; # use your own consumer key here
$humblr = new Humblr($baseHostname, $tumblrConsumerKey);

$post = $humblr->getPosts(array('limit' => 1));
print_r($post);
```

This works fine and gives me a result of something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [blog_name] => name 
        [id] => 43993 
        [post_url] => http://name.tumblr.com/post/43993/
        [slug] => slug 
        [type] => video 
        [date] => 2013-02-25 18:00:25 GMT 
        [timestamp] => 1361815225 
        [state] => published 
        [format] => html )
```

I try and display some values like this:

```
echo "The blog name is: ".$post->blog_name;
echo $post->id;
```

However, it is blank. How can I display these values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, turn on [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74847/what-is-the-recommended-error-reporting-setting-for-development-what-about-e?rq=1).

```
// error reporting for development environment
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

As @Zlatan points out, it's an *array* of stdClass's.

After you enable error reporting, you will error notices *"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ..."* for this code:

```
echo "The blog name is: ".$post->blog_name;
echo $post->id;
```

Because you're trying to access an non-object.

You can fix it by accessing the object through it's array index:

```
echo "The blog name is: ".$post[0]->blog_name;
echo $post[0]->id;
```

Assuming `$posts`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [blog_name] => blog1
            [id] => 10234
            [post_url] => http://name.tumblr.com/post/43993/
            [slug] => slug
            [type] => video1
            [date] => 2013-02-25 18:00:25 GMT
            [timestamp] => 1361815225
            [state] => published
            [format] => html
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [blog_name] => blog2
            [id] => 20234
            [post_url] => http://name.tumblr.com/post/43993/
            [slug] => slug1
            [type] => video
            [date] => 2013-02-25 18:00:25 GMT
            [timestamp] => 1361815225
            [state] => published
            [format] => html
        )

)
```

Accessing objects by array index:

```
echo "The blog name is: ".$post[0]->blog_name;
echo $post[0]->id;
echo "The blog name is: ".$post[1]->blog_name;
echo $post[1]->id;

// prints
// The blog name is: blog1
// 10234
// The blog name is: blog2
// 20234
```

If you want to loop the posts:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo "The blog name is: ".$post->blog_name;
    echo $post->id;
}

// prints
// The blog name is: blog1
// 10234
// The blog name is: blog2
// 20234
```

### Resources

- [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) (PHP Manual)
- [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) (PHP Manual)

Answer (score 1):

As I see it's an Array, so you can try:

```
echo $post[0]->blog_name;
```