# Joomla 1.5 font page blank page

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am new to the Joomla CMS I would like to say first. The server the website was being hosted on just updated their PHP the 5.4. It worked correctly for a time then the front page stopped displaying anything. I have tried almost everything that's suggested to fix the problem but nothing seems to work. From checking the error_log, exporting the website and re installing it on a new hosting service that still supports PHP 5.2, viewed the PHP errors and made small changes to the file's code that logged as syntax errors so they wouldn't occur and nothing, still blank. Starting from scratch is not on options for me because I need to keep that template intact since I was not the one that created it. If anyone out there has any suggestion it would be appreciated.

When turning on the error reporting in the configuration file I get

Beginning error messages

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\restore\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\restore\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getApplication() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\restore\index.php on line 31

Strict Standards: Declaration of JSite::getPathWay() should be compatible with that of JApplication::getPathway() in C:\xampp\htdocs\restore\includes\application.php on line 377

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRegistryFormat::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\restore\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 373

Ending error messages

just list a few. I have tried going through and editing them with now luck.

Comment: Without error log there's not much we can help you with. Go to `configuration.php` and make sure to set `$debug = '1';`

Comment: Also, make sure that your `php.ini` is setup with `debugger.enabled=on`

Comment: Joomla 1.5 is old and PHP 5.4 is relatively new. There will obviously be issues. Try upgrading to Joomla 2.5 or 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. On if its modules was causing the blank page error in some way.
I was able to find this out by first making a copy of the current site using Akeeba Backup plugin.
Installed is on my localhost.
Installed a fresh version of Joomla 1.5 (with out default data)
Then edited the configuration.php file's database connection settings

```
/* Database Settings */
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'root';
var $password = 'password';
var $db = 'dbname';
var $dbprefix = 'jos_';
```

to use the database created from the copied version of the website I installed on my localhost.

With that being done the fresh version of joomla I created had all the database information
I needed to recreate a new website with the same content.

I then started copying the components, modules, plugins, template, and modules from the copied
version to the fresh version.
Note: Some of the plugins and modules needed to be re-installed.

I would check to see if the fresh version was still functioning correctly every time I copied a directory over. Then, bam I got a blank front end page on the fresh version after I copies over a certain module.

So I found a version of the module that worked for 1.5  on the W3 and re-installed it.
Solving the mystery of my blank front end page.

It took quite a few hours to pinpoint the problem but I'm thankful for the people that responded to my question on the forums I posted it on. And I hope this can help anyone out there that comes across a mysterious blank front end page.

Answer (score 1):

This issue really isn't a Joomla specific one, but PHP. To learn more about troubleshooting these issues in PHP, there is a good discussion at [How to get useful error messages in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and [What is the recommended error_reporting() setting for development? What about E_STRICT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74847/what-is-the-recommended-error-reporting-setting-for-development-what-about-e)